# App Must Verify The Authenticity Of The Request From Shopify

Tags: shopify, laravel-8, webhooks, shopify-app

Expected HTTP 401 (Unauthorized), but got HTTP 405 from shop-redact. Your app's HTTPS webhook endpoints must validate the HMAC digest of each request, and return an

> HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)

response when rejecting a request that has an invalid digest.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7we08.png)

I have used `osiset/laravel-shopify` package

I have solved this error. Even though one app has been approved, the other app has the same solution in front of it, I still get this error from Shopify in the other app.

1. First I tried this solution in which the app was rejected. But I applied the same solution in the first app, which was approved

   ```
    Route::get('/shop-redact',[AbcController::class,'shopRedact'])->middleware('auth.webhook')->name('shop.redact');
   ```
2. And then I tried to create a job for all GDPR webhook but the app was rejected
   https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/GDPR

What is the other solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify webhooks make POST request to your endpoint so set post request

```
Route::post('/shop-redact',[AbcController::class,'shopRedact'])->middleware('auth.webhook')->name('shop.redact');
```